# Use cookies to only show my pop up only once?

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to add cookie control to my popup so it only shows once.

```
 var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
 var close = document.getElementById("myDiv");
 var element = document.getElementById("myDiv");

 function popupScroll() {
    element.classList.add("show-modal");
 }
 function closeModal() {
    element.classList.add("hide-modal");
 }
 window.addEventListener("scroll", popupScroll);
 window.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We expect a proper problem description from you, and “I’m struggling” isn’t one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

While `localStorage` accesses the current domain's **local** Storage object and adds a data item to it, `sessionStorage`accesses the current domain's **session** Storage object and adds a data item to it.

```
    var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
    var close = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    var element = document.getElementById("myDiv");

    function popupScroll() {
        if (!localStorage.getItem('showPopup')) { //check if popup has already been shown, if not then proceed
            localStorage.setItem('showPopup', 'true'); // Set the flag in localStorage
            element.classList.add("show-modal");
        }
    }
    function closeModal() {
        element.classList.add("hide-modal");
    }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", popupScroll);
    window.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
```

Remember, while an item that has been set in `sessionStorage` lasts as long your browser session, the `localStorage` items don't have expiration times. That being said, in your current case, you could use either `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's done exactly what I wanted it to. You're a star !!

Answer (score 1):

I advice to use `localStorage`. Its a Javascript API with functions like `setItem` and `getItem`. Here an example:

```
function displayPopup() {
  //if the variable in localStorage is set dont show the popup and just return
  if (localStorage.getItem('popupAlreadyShown')) return;

  //display popup, example: 
  document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
}

function closePopup() {
  //close popup, example: 
  document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
  //set the variable in localStorage that the popup is closed
  localStorage.setItem('popupAlreadyShown', 'true');
}
```